# backup a single table in postgresql with less time

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to backup a single table which has 20 columns and 4 million rows in postgres, even after i try to take a parallel dump, I don't see any difference in time taken to backup the table. It almost takes 50 minutes. How can i reduce it? Table Partitioning is not an option.

Comment: I think parallel selects are available from 9.6 only and pg_dump with jobs would parallely select SEVERAL tables, so in your position I think you can't

Comment: How exactly are you creating that backup? Please show us the exact command.

Comment: Pg_dump -t tbl -d dbname -Fd -j 8 > /tmp/dir/